# Ruby dynamically instantiate class

Tags: ruby

How to reference to a class within a static method?

```
class Car
  def self.new_from_xml(xml)
    instance = self.class.new
    #do some stuff with xml
    instance
  end
end

class Mercedes < Car
end

class Porsche < Car
end
```

IRB:

```
Mercedes.new_from_xml(somedata) # Output is #<Class:...>, should be #<Mercedes:...>
Porsche.new_from_xml(somedata)  # Output is #<Class:...>, should be #<Porsche:...>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
instance=self.class.new
```

just write

```
instance = new
```

**Why is this?**

Well, in first place, you have to understand that you are calling a class method, thus you are at a class level already. The .new method is a class method, so you can call it directly without calling self.class.new.

**Why does self.class.new return Class?**

Because the class of the class Car is Class (I know, sounds weird ;), because classes in Ruby are instances of Class.

This is actually a pretty deep concept, I recommend you read more about it. One nice reference I have read is the book Metaprogramming Ruby by Paolo Perrotta (ISBN-10: 1934356476) [1].

1. [http://www.amazon.com/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Pros/dp/1934356476](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already in a class method, you should use `self.new` (or simply `new`, as @tokland wrote) instead of `self.class.new`:

```
class Car
   def self.new_from_xml(xml)
       instance = new
       #do some stuff with xml
   end
end

class Mercedes < Car
end

class Porsche < Car
end

p Mercedes.new_from_xml(nil) #=> #<Mercedes:0x007f042d0db208>
p Porsche.new_from_xml(nil) #=> #<Porsche:0x007f042d0db118>
```

---

From a comment to this answer: *Why does self.class reference to class? What's the logic here?*

Inside a class block `self` references the class you are editing:

```
class Car
  puts self #=> writes Car
end
```

Using `def self.new_from_xml` it is like if you are declaring `def Car.new_from_xml`, that is a method of the `Car` object (which is an instance of `Class`); so inside `new_from_xml` `self` coincides with `Car`.

Comment: or simply `new`. Also, you can fix the unidiomatic style (spaces, indentation) of the question :-)

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Why does self.class reference to class? Whats the logic here?